# SQL - sum data for all time, 30 days and 90 days for multiple columns indiviually

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

**BACKGROUND:**

I have data that looks like this

```
date        src    subsrc   subsubsrc   param1  param2
2020-02-01  src1    ksjd    dfd8        47      31    
2020-02-02  src1    djsk    zmnc        44      95    
2020-02-03  src2    skdj    awes        92      100   
2020-02-04  src2    mxsf    kajs        80      2     
2020-02-05  src3    skdj    asio        46      53    
2020-02-06  src3    dekl    jdqo        19      18    
2020-02-07  src3    dskl    dqqq        69      18    
2020-02-08  src4    sqip    riow        64      46    
2020-02-09  src5    ss01    qwep        34      34
```

I am trying to aggregate for all time, last 30 days and last 90 days (no rolling sum)

So my final data would look like this:

```
src     subsrc  subsubsrc   p1_all  p1_30   p1_90   p2_all  p2_30   p2_90
src1    ksjd    dfd8        7       1       7       98      7        98
src1    djsk    zmnc        0       0       0       0       0         0
src2    skdj    awes        12      12      12      4       4         4
src2    mxsf    kajs        6       6       6       31      31       31
src3    skdj    asio        0       0       0       0       0         0
src3    dekl    jdqo        20      20      20      17      17        17
src3    dskl    dqqq        3       3       3       4       4         4
src4    sqip    qwep        0       0       0       0       0         0
src5    ss01    qwes        15      15      15      2       2         2
```

**ABOUT DATA:**

- This is only dummy data and therefore incorrect.
- There are tens of thousands of rows in my data.
- There are a dozen of src columns that make up the key for the table.
- There are a dozen of param columns that I have to sum for 30 and 90 and all time.
- Also there are null values in param columns.
- Also there are might be multiple rows for same day and src column.
- New data is being added every day and the query is probably going to be run every day to get the latest 30, 90, all time data.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

This is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT src, subsubsrc, subsubsrc,
SUM(param1) as param1_all,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE,date,day) <= 30 THEN param1 END) as param1_30,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE,date,day) <= 90 THEN param1 END) as param1_90,
SUM(param2) as param2_all,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE,date,day) <= 30 THEN param2 END) as param2_30,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE,date,day) <= 90 THEN param2 END) as param2_90,
FROM `MY_TABLE`
GROUP BY src
ORDER BY src
```

This actually works but I can anticipate how long this query is going to become for multiple sources and even more param columns.

I have been trying something called "**Filtered aggregate functions (or manual pivot)**" explained [HERE](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/). But I am unable to understand/implement it for my case.

Also  I have looked at dozens of answers and most of them are running sums for each day OR are complicated cases of this basic calculation. Maybe I am not searching it correctly.

As you can see I am newbie in SQL and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or Big Query? These are two different database products, please tag only the relevant one.

Comment: Its MySQL, I would be writing the new table in Google Cloud SQL. I was testing the query in BigQuery because of the interface and speed and incorrectly tagged bigquery.

Comment: How can I know the reason for a question being marked to close.

Comment: "Tens of thousands"?  I doubt if it will take more than 1 second.  Is that fast enough?

Comment: @RickJames. As a coder, lots of duplication was bothering me. I just feel it can be improved. Also the data is going to grow over time.

Answer (score 4):

Your query looks quite good; conditional aggregation is the canonical method to pivot a dataset.

One way to possibly increase performance would be to change the date filter in the conditional expressions: using a date function precludes the use of an index.

Instead, you could phrase this as:

```
select 
    src, 
    subsrc, 
    subsubsrc,
    sum(param1) as param1_all,
    sum(case when date >= current_date - interval 30 day then param1 end) as param1_30,
    sum(case when date >= current_date - interval 90 day then param1 end) as param1_90,
    sum(param2) as param2_all,
    sum(case when date >= current_date - interval 30 day then param2 end) as param2_30,
    sum(case when date >= current_date - interval 90 day then param2 end) as param2_90
from my_table
group by src, subsrc, subsubsrc
order by src, subsrc, subsubsrc
```

For performance, the following index may be helpul: `(src, subsrc, subsubsrc, date)`.

Note that I included all three non-aggregated columns (`src, subsrc, subsubsrc`) in the `group by` clause: starting MySQL 5.7, this is by default mandatory (although you can play around with sql modes to alter that behavior) - and most other databases implement the same constraint.

Comment: Upvoting because this answer is faster and/or cleaner than the rest of the answers.

Comment: @RickJames: from a MySQL performance guru like you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach isn't a bad one if you are able to build the query programmatically. One alternative might be to create side tables for the 30 and 90 day cases first so you can effectively select all columns from each. This could also be done in sub-queries but there are performance considerations.

Some untested pseudo code to hopefully clarify:

```
SELECT 
 src,
 subsrc,
 subsubsrc,
 SUM(param1) as param1_all,
 -- other "all" sums here
 SUM(t30.param1) as param1_30,
 -- other "30" sums here
 SUM(t90.param1) as param1_90,
 -- other "90" sums here
FROM MY_TABLE
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
) as t30 on t30.src = MY_TABLE.src
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
) as t90 on t90.src = MY_TABLE.src
GROUP BY MY_TABLE.src
ORDER BY MY_TABLE.src
```

Note the date conditions have been switched to not use a function on the date column but instead compare to a date value. Your original approach would defeat any index on date (which you will want to make this more efficient).

If you first put these sub-queries into side tables that have a key on src the joins will be more efficient too. You could even group/sum directly into those side tables first rather than creating larger copies of your data, and then join the aggregated data together.

Comment: Thank you for this. But as mentioned I have like 20 src columns and 20 param columns (to be summed). I just feel that given the work is more like repetitive work there might be a smarter way to do this. For now I ll just go with this. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, this reduces some of the repetition (not having the put the date condition everywhere) but maybe doesn't solve your main problem. There are likely ways to do that using stored procedures or prepared statements that build the query, which is something I try to avoid because I find it a little more foreign and feel it makes the code harder to understand/share down the road. Maybe someone else will show us a really clean way to do that though. I assume you are writing this SQL directly and not querying from within some application code.

Comment: Yeah the day level table is in Cloud SQL and I am creating a new table with 30 90 also in Cloud SQL. if that is what you are asking. I am myself not an expert but lets see if we can learn something new through this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. Your RDBMS needs to loop all records under the hood and do some calculations. One thing that you can improve is that you are calculating date differences for all records. It would make sense to calculate the moment 30 days ago and 90 days ago beforehand, respectively and only compare the dates against those.

Since you already know that the number of rows and parameters will increase in the future, it makes sense to create a cron job which daily computes this in the following manner:

- the first time it calculates the values, it should store all the results along with the date it was running at (maybe into a table dedicated for this analytics)
- on subsequent days you can calculate the all time sum by loading the items which were created since the last check
- you will still need to calculate the 30 and 90 day stuff, but that would be much less of a problem than calculating this for all time

If you do this properly and have daily information, then later on you will be able to analyze trends in history as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use 3 different queries for that:

1. Sum for all time
2. Sum for 30 days
3. Sum for 90 days

Because when you're trying to do all-in-1 query then you end up with full table scan because of `CASE-WHEN-END` (BTW there is compact form `IF()` in MySQL). This is extremely non-optimal.

If you split it into 3 different queries and add an index to the `date` column then it won't do full-scan for the 2nd and 3rd query. Only for the 1st query, which can be optimised separately (for example by caching).

Also this approach: `DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE,date,day) <= 90`

should be changed to: `date >= 'date-90-days-ago'` (where `'date-90-days-ago'` is a fixed date)

Thus you won't have to compute difference of 2 dates for every row. You'll have just to compute 2 dates: 30 days ago and 90 days ago and compare all other dates to these two. This approach will benefit of the `date` column index.

Comment: Instead of created 3 queries do you think something like a single subquery that can be used as filter on multiple columns is possible. I found something like `Filtered aggregate functions (or manual pivot)` (link shared above) which looked promising.

Comment: Thanks for the `IF()` statement instead of `CASE-WHEN-END`.

Comment: Lastly I can not use a fixed date since the data is going to be updated every day.

Comment: also for each of the 3 queries you mentioned would have the same src columns and sum on the same param columns and even the same condition on date (except for 30, 90 and all value). I just feel there should be neat, concise way to do it.

Comment: You don't need to provide `date-90-days-ago`, MySQL is happy to provide that constant via `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY` -- and it will be just as fast.